# Populating a Tapku Calendar with Data from an Array of Dictionaries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I have an array full of dictionaries corresponding to a homework object.
Each dictionary has an entry named Date holding an NSDate!
Each dictionary also has an entry for Title holding an NSString
I want to use a TAPKU calendar to show, in the table view below, the Title string if the user taps on a date and there is a homework due on that day!
How can I achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Looked for tutorials but have been unable to find any updated ones!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the updated Tapku demo project provided the exact answer I needed!
https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary

Answer (score 2):

Tapku calendar has a method

```
- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)d {}`
```

where "d" is the date tapped. With this date you can do everything. Use it in class where you implement the calendar.

My example, where i change title of button with data from array witch contains text for a lot of dates:

```
- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)d {
    [self setEditButtonTitle:d];
}

- (void)setEditButtonTitle : (NSDate*) d{
    for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
        if (/*  compare if NSDate from my array is equal to "d" */){
            [editButton setTitle:[array objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

Part with homework i don't understand :(